# Text gets squashed when re-sizing web browser HTML | CSS

Tags: html, css

The text on my website will not re-size correctly when making the browser
window smalller.
it squashes the text in the middle and makes more lines.
here is my code

**My whole document**

html: http://pastebin.com/kj1jvTjv
css:http://pastebin.com/A1CP7Viq

HTML:

```
</div>
<div id="NewsPosts">
<p>Toontown Classic is coming soon</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#NewsPosts{
position: relative;
bottom: 0px;
top: -925px;
width: 45%;
position: center; 
margin: 0 auto;
font-size: 20px; 
margin-left: 10; 
margin-right: 10; 
text-indent: 5; 
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify this: "The text ... will not resize correctly..."

You want the font size to decrease?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell exactly how you want it to work from your question. If you want the `font-size` to dynamically change based on the view size of the browser, you could use `vw` units (see jsfiddle preview and code example below).

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/km1hbpzv/1/ Try resizing the browser to see if that is the effect you want.

I worked off of the HTML and CSS you posted on Pastebin, but I added in the CSS from your original post and edited it.

My changes:

```
#NewsPosts {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0px;
   top: -925px;
   width: 45%;
   //position: center; changed this to text-align: center (below)
   text-align: center;
   margin: 0 auto;
   //font-size: 20px; changed this to 2vw which is percentage of the viewport width
   font-size: 2vw;
   margin-left: 10; 
   margin-right: 10; 
   text-indent: 5; 
}

#DateAndBy {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: -930px;
    //font-size: 30px; changed this to 3vw which is a percentage of viewport width
    font-size: 3vw;
    margin-left: 10; 
    margin-right: 10; 
    text-indent: 5; 
}
```

There may be structural problems with your HTML that make later styling changes harder to implement, but this seems to work at the moment based on the information I could collect from your post.

Further discussion related to `vw` units and other `font-size` practices may be found here: [Pure CSS to make font-size responsive based on dynamic amount of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters)

Answer (score 0):

`center` is not a valid value for `position`, so you can't do `position: center;`. If you want to center a div in a window, you can set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` property to `auto`. I see you do this with the line `margin: 0 auto;`, but then you override that two lines later with `margin-left: 10; 
margin-right: 10;`. `10` is also not a valid value for `margin`, it needs to be `10px` or `10em` or some value with a specifier after it. Also for something like this, `position: relative` is unnecessary, although depending on your other HTML elements, this might break something. So, use this CSS:

```
#NewsPosts {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 45%;
}
```

Something like that should do what you want.

Comment: Could you post your whole HTML and CSS document?

Comment: posted it on pastebin