# Fit to text within the div

Tags: javascript, html

I need fit text within the fixed width container, for example i have 150px width in particular div but text is dynamically will come so based one font size change and fit to the container, kindly suggest

Note:
only javascript

Comment: why adding the css tag if you don't want a CSS-based solution ? :)

Comment: Create a https://jsfiddle.net/ to show us what you've tried.

Comment: on the `p/span/h` tag add `width: inherit` to css - should work :) (can be done with pure js/jQuery - I know in jQuery is `$('#elem').css('prop', 'value')` - no idea what that is in pure js

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs  I think OP wants to change the font size so the text fits within the 150px div no matter how long it is

Comment: @Pete ah I see! Then `overflow: scroll` is needed or something similar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to: Reduce font-size if a line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485351/how-to-reduce-font-size-if-a-line-breaks)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this method, stolen from this answer:

[How to: Reduce font-size if a line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485351/how-to-reduce-font-size-if-a-line-breaks/28485608#28485608)

Written by AlexK

```js
var divWidth = $("#theDiv").width();
var text = $("#text");
var fontSize = 12;

while (text.width() > divWidth)
  text.css("font-size", fontSize -= 0.5);

text.css("display", "inline");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="theDiv" style="width:200px; border:1px solid red;">
  <span id="text" style="display:none;white-space:nowrap;">This sentence is too large to fit within the div.</span>
</div>
```

Note that you need JQuery for this.

If you don't want to use jQuery, it shouldn't be hard to replace it with JS.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ub91k1ku/)