# Automatically Adjust the Font Size of the Text in order to fit in a Div

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a div with a class `myid_print_duo_college`.

```
.myid_print_duo_college
{
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: 365px;
    color: #0C6A13;
    width: 246px;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;  
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Cooper Std Black";   
    border: 1px solid black;      
}
```

The layout turnouts good , when the text is just short. See image below:

[image]

But when the text is long, the layout will be messed up like the image below:

[image]

How will I automatically adjust the font size of the text in order to fit in a div?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container  ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters

Comment: Use `vw` units for `font-size` , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths

Comment: Example with `vw` : http://jsfiddle.net/mjzuakcn/1/

Comment: For font resizing to fit a fixed-width container, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940499/text-size-auto-resizing-on-div-width/30960832#30960832