# Text-size auto resizing on div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I struggle with one problem. I have a div with a specific width and height (227px x 27px). Inside this div comes First and Last name, as a variable. Sometimes this name is small so there is a plenty of space in the div, but sometimes the name is long, and i need to resize the text that it could fit the div. I would like to also have max font size defined

my HTML code looks like this:

```
<div class="Basic-Text-Frame _idGenPageitem-6" id="fitin">
  <p class="Basic-Paragraph ParaOverride-1">
     <span class="CharOverride-2" ><?php echo $userdata->display_name;?></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.Basic-Text-Frame {
 border-style:solid;
}
p.Basic-Paragraph {
  color:#000000;
  font-family:"Minion Pro", serif;
  font-size:12px;
  font-style:normal;
  font-variant:normal;
  font-weight:normal;
  line-height:1.2;
  margin-bottom:0;
  margin-left:0;
  margin-right:0;
  margin-top:0;
  orphans:1;
  page-break-after:auto;
  page-break-before:auto;
  text-align:left;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-indent:0;
  text-transform:none;
  widows:1;
}
div._idGenPageitem-6 {
  height:27px;
  left:0px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  width:227px;
  z-index:0;
}
p.ParaOverride-1 {
  text-align:center;
}
span.CharOverride-2 {
  color:#5b9b98;
  font-family:Garamond, serif;
  font-size:x-large;
  font-style:normal;
  font-variant:small-caps;
  font-weight:normal;
  text-transform:none;
  max-height: 29px;
}
```

EDIT: i have tried [resize font-size according to div size](http://resize%20font-size%20according%20to%20div%20size), and [this suggested answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112660/how-to-automatically-resize-the-size-of-text-inside-a-div/6112914#6112914) and [flowType plugin](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/) and [FitText plugin](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) before and i coudnt make it, that is why i aksed the question.

my problem is that bigger text just goes in new row, and is not fitted accordingly to the this div box. So long text result is out of the div and could not been seen. As I put the span height "absolute" value, it always changes to "auto"

Here is the picture of the problem i am working on [image: it is a intensification card]

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358181/resize-font-size-according-to-div-size

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/6112914/909535

Comment: Here's a jQuery plugin which may help.
http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/

Comment: Thank you all
I have tried all of this solution before i asked the question, but non of these have worked out for me.
I have edited the question with all the details i work with

Comment: try giving it more width...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this function on page load to resize the text if necessary. The important thing in the css is `white-space: nowrap` which stops the text from wrapping onto a second line.
Don't forget to give the test span "d" the same font family, style and weight as the real text.

```js
function fittext()
{
    var maxW = 227, maxH = 27, maxSize = 20;
    var c = document.getElementsByClassName("fitin");
    var d = document.createElement("span");
    d.style.fontSize = maxSize + "px";

    for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++)
    {
        d.innerHTML = c[i].innerHTML;
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        var w = d.offsetWidth;
        var h = d.offsetHeight;
        document.body.removeChild(d);
        var x = w > maxW ? maxW / w : 1;
        var y = h > maxH ? maxH / h : 1;
        var r = Math.min(x, y) * maxSize;
        c[i].style.fontSize = r + "px";
    }
}

fittext();
```

```css
DIV
{
    width: 227px;
    height: 27px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
    background-color: silver;
}

P
{
    margin: 0px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<DIV>
    <P>
         <SPAN CLASS="fitin">Short Guy</SPAN>
    </P>
</DIV>
<DIV>
    <P>
         <SPAN CLASS="fitin">Just A Random Regular Person</SPAN>
    </P>
</DIV>
<DIV>
    <P>
         <SPAN CLASS="fitin">A Really Very Extraordinarily Long And Tall Woman</SPAN>
    </P>
</DIV>
```