# Is it possible to change font size if height of the box is too big with only CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

I have some title absolutly positioned over an image and for some articles it gets too big and overflows, which looks ugly.

I wonder if it is possible to use `@media(max-height:200px)` that usually refers to the viewport, to refer to an element, and change its style when the box gets too big.

My first thought was "this is not possible", but seems to be always a way to do stuff when you ask to the right person.

**EDIT: For a more concrete understanding: I have an `h2` with `font-size: 2em`, and I'd like to make it `1.5em`, if the text is longer than 2 lines.**

Comment: Javascript could be a option

Comment: I know I could do it with JS, but I wonder if there is a creative way to do this even if it is not 100% reliable

Comment: Have you already tried the break the words in a new line. Eg with `word-break`/`word-wrap` CSS-properties.

Comment: An image showing the issue would be helpful. I suspect absolute positioning and word-wrap may offer a suitable solution.

Comment: Simply...no. Element based media queries don't exist yet so JS is the only option here.

Comment: Could you please provide a code with html and css?

Comment: What style would you want to change it to?

Comment: I have an h2 with font-size: 2em, and I'd like to make it 1.5em, if the text is longer than 2 lines

Comment: For the javascript option, I answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940499/text-size-auto-resizing-on-div-width/30960832#30960832