# Make text fit box no matter how big text is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having problem trying to fit a long text inside a box. I can't change the size of the box due to client's design specification so I have to get the text to fit the box instead. It can be achieved with html css js or jquery it doesn't matter as long as I get to the desired effect.

[Here's my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h49u1kxa/1/)

```
<div class="mybutton">
  <div class="myproblem">
    MyNameIs30CharactersLong
  </div>
  <div class="myproblem2">
    MyNameIsShort
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's how it is with a long name:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Set your font size according to percentage, or according to viewport.

Comment: If my user has a short name it fits the box, if my user has a really long name it doesn't fit and overflow as you guys see above, I don't want the box to re-size, I want the text to shrink and fit the box. viewport wouldn't help bc we're  not talking about resolutions. I don't think it's a duplicate since the other solutions didn't solve my problem Anthony.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters -- this answer mentions using `vw` units for pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://jquery-textfill.github.io/

This might help your issue with text resizing.