# Font Resizing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, size

I am designing a website based on percentages, so that the website mostly contained within divs and tables adapts depending on screen resolution. The issue is I have not found a way for the font size to do that same. As the font size remains static, this means it looks different on different screen resolutions and the text will break at certain points on some screens where it would not on other screens, which in turn can mess up the look of the website. Is there anyway to get font-size to adapt depending on the screen resolution?

Comment: You need to show what you've already tried.

Comment: Try using [vh or vw units](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/) for font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possibility. It has its drawbacks, as noted in the answer.

[Pure CSS to make font-size responsive based on dynamic amount of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters)

Comment: thanks . will look into this.