# CSS word div scale down

Tags: html, css, scale

In the situation, In the same row,  i have word in the left and image in the right. The problem is when i try to resize the browser, the image div will scale small(the width and height will adjust smaller) but the word div will not scale small at the same time. (the word div just resize the width but the same height)  How can i fix it properly?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ALRZGa

```
  <div class=container>
   <div class="word">
   <h1>Hello</h1>
   </div>

   <div class=picture>
   <figure> <img src="...">
   </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: can you create a minimal simplified example showing the problem?

Comment: That depends on the styles. I'll bet you have a width in % for the img. If that's what you want for the word too, use a font-size in vw.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters)

Comment: i cannot use the height:100% or auto.  I have to make the fixed height (eg. 500px for the word div) so it cannot be scale properly. how can i do

Comment: You have to make the sample on jsfiddle or on codepen, so everyone can understand what is wrong.

Comment: update with code pen

Comment: I just want to resize the browser (scale small the picture div and word div at the same time)   scale both width and height.  The key problem should be the fixed height of word div

Comment: the word div h1 is absolutely positioned... hence won't resize on browser resize... also the word div is over the image and they are not side by side as per your question...