# Making bootstrap header with text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

On smaller devices, `title` goes out of the screen. If I reload the page, it looks good for a second then it overflows. Is there something I haven't considered?

I'm trying to make a full screen header with text and a button and this is what I have done so far:

```css
/*body, html {
  height: 100%;
}*/

body {
  margin: 0px 0px;
}

#full {
  background-image:url(https://chrisaam.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/wallpaper-2846361.jpg);
  background-size:cover;
  position: relative;
  height:100vh;
}

.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 36px;
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%); /* Safari */
  transform: translate(0,-50%);  
}
```

```html
<div id="full">  
    <div class="header">
        <h1 class="title">ACCENTOMETER</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-default header-scroll">PLAY NOW</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I checked it out on mobile ... It works fine bro !

Comment: Thanks, it looks weird on Chrome when I use mobile view

Answer (score 1):

CSS3 supports new dimensions that are relative to view port. But this doesn't work in android < 4.4

You can use dimensions in % or em. Just change the base font size everything will change. This way the font size will change with the device.

```
@media (max-width: @screen-xs) {
    body{font-size: 10px;}
}

@media (max-width: @screen-sm) {
    body{font-size: 14px;}
}

h5{
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

Look at all the ways at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21981859/406659

You can also use simple media queries for changing the font size respective to various screen sizes. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px){

  .title{

    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

You can also play around with viewport width and viewport height. You can check [Viewport Units](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/) for more detail.

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width

1vh = 1% of viewport height

1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller

1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger

h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On small device try adding col width for this device

```
<div id="full">     
   <div class="header col-sm-12  col-xs-12 " >
      <h1 class="title col-xs-12">ACCENTOMETER</h1>
      <button class="btn btn-default header-scroll col-xs-12">PLAY NOW</button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can make the title responsive by using javascript along with css style properties.**

First you need to get the width of your browser window. Then make some appropriate formula for a `responsive_font` using window width size.

Using `responsive_font` you can make your title responsive.

For Example :

```
function title_fontsize(){

var title=document.getElementById("mytitle");
var win_size=window.innerWidth;  
responsive_font=win_size/(20)+"px";
title.style.fontSize=responsive_font;

}
```