# Make display headings responsive

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap's "display-2" class, and I need to make the text responsive / smaller when I go in smaller devices.

Dramatically Engage

[[image: The text looks like this[1]]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pure CSS to make font-size responsive based on dynamic amount of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you provide a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your text responsive you just have to use **mediaquery** in css file.

Media query is a CSS technique introduced in **CSS3**.
It uses the **@media** rule to include a block of CSS properties only if a certain condition is true.

index.html

```
    <div>
      <h1 class="heading">Dramaticall Engage</h1>
    </div>
```

style.css

```
    .heading{
         font-size: 30px;
      }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

      .heading{
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 425px) {

      .heading{
        font-size: 14px;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `@media` query for responsive size of fonts as per screen size and any content.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
```