# How to make text fit all div's width?

Tags: html, css

There is a block on my site, where user's work price is written. All users have different price of work, so if text length is more than 5 letters, the text wont fit the parent block.

[image]

I'd like to solve this problem with no javascript code if possible

Comment: Can you provide a working example of the problem? (HTML and CSS)

Comment: can you show the code you are using?

Comment: Yes, please show the code. As-is, if you simply don't know what the width of the text will be, then style the box to fit whatever the maximum could be.

Comment: yes, sure here it is https://codepen.io/CitizenOne/pen/bPOpBr there is no font and images, but that's not important for solving the problem

Comment: try looking into em and rem

Comment: What is the parent display? If it's a flex box the children will grow automatically, then you can apply flex-wrap to the parent, just in case the children try to grow out of width

Comment: I have edited the codepen  - https://codepen.io/mightyteja/pen/mZaPBO

Answer (score 0):

I think your only two options are adjusting the with of the "box" or the font size. I would try to use `display: inline;` or `display: inline-block` on your "box" and not setting the width explicitly. With that it should always match the with of the text.

```css
.box {
  display: inline;
  background: #cccccc;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
 100 $
</div>
<div class="box">
 1000 $
</div>
<div class="box">
 1000 $
</div>
```

Comment: I already thought about this. But that's the website design would disagree with this solution.

Here is the scrin:

https://ibb.co/6b7NvTG

Comment: I mean these blocks should have fixed width

Comment: If you need a fixed with, you could try looking at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45863608/5254957), which suggests calculating the font size based on the width and height of the containing div like this `font-size: calc(4vw + 4vh + 2vmin);`

Comment: this will work only if parent element is html or parent's width and height equal to the browser width and height

Answer (score 0):

You have four options:

1. Make all grey blocks longer
2. Give each grey block a dynamic `width`
3. Make all the text smaller
4. Give each text a dynamic `font-size`

Options 1) and 3) have the advantage of giving your page a uniform appearance.

Options 2) and 4) have the advantage of only altering the appearance of a grey block (and the text it contains) when necessary.

If you declare `display: inline-block` for a `div` and do not explicitly set a `width` for that `div`, then it will have an implicit width based on its content. See below for an example.

**Working Example using dynamic widths:**

```css
div {
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
margin: 12px 6px;
padding: 12px;
font-size: 24px;
text-align: center;
color: rgb(0, 127, 0);
background-color: rgb(227, 227, 227);
border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>3000₽</div>
<div>300000₽</div>
<div>300000000₽</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Without using JS to query for width, then your only option is to change the size of the box, or change the size of the text.