# PHP scale number up/down based on input?

Tags: php, numbers

Using the length of a string, I want to scale the font size up/down based on that.

So, lower string length, higher number. Higher string length, lower number.

But I don't want to do dozens upon dozens of if/else or a switch statement. Ideally I'd programmatically scale the output based on the input.

Something like...

```
  text_length = strlen($full_text)
  size_range = range(0, 5)
  
  // if text_length = 1 then 100% of size_range
  // if text_length = 280 then 0% of size_range
```

In this case, the maximum text length is 280 (they're tweets).

Comment: Can you use javascript or jQuery for the same or even better css?

Comment: @JitendraYadav Have tried quite a few solutions using jQuery, plain JS and CSS. All had their drawbacks, so giving this method a try now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431411/pure-css-to-make-font-size-responsive-based-on-dynamic-amount-of-characters/21981859 try this

Comment: I appreciate the link, but not what I'm looking for. Those solutions breakdown with multiple lines and I want more control over things.

Comment: okies, will check then what can I help you with.

Answer (score 0):

If the plot of [y = 1/-279x + 280/279](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281%2F-279%29x+%2B+280%2F279) reflects what you want.

[image: plot of requested result]

I did the following script in Ruby that should be easy to translate to PHP:

```rb
require "bundler/inline"

gemfile do
  gem "rspec"
end

require "rspec/autorun"

MAX_SIZE_PERCENTAGE = 1.0

def size_it(text_length, maximum_length)
  alpha = - MAX_SIZE_PERCENTAGE / (maximum_length - MAX_SIZE_PERCENTAGE)
  beta = maximum_length / (maximum_length - MAX_SIZE_PERCENTAGE)
  ((alpha * text_length) + beta).round(2)
end

RSpec.describe "dynamic size calculation" do
  it "100% when minimal size" do
    text_length = 1
    maximum_size = 280
    expect(size_it(text_length, maximum_size)).to eq(1)
  end

  it "75% when almost too short" do
    text_length = 70
    maximum_size = 280
    expect(size_it(text_length, maximum_size)).to eq(0.75)
  end

  it "50% when half point" do
    text_length = 140
    maximum_size = 280
    expect(size_it(text_length, maximum_size)).to eq(0.5)
  end

  it "25% when almost too long" do
    text_length = 210
    maximum_size = 280
    expect(size_it(text_length, maximum_size)).to eq(0.25)
  end

  it "0% when maximum size" do
    text_length = 280
    maximum_size = 280
    expect(size_it(text_length, maximum_size)).to eq(0)
  end
end
```

The math is intuitive, a few landmines:

- integer division, e.g 1/280 resulting in 0 instead of 0.0003, I prevented this by calling `.to_f`, Ruby way to cast to float.
- rounding errors, expecting 0.25 and getting 0.2503213, I adjusted this by calling `round(2)`, Ruby way to round to nearest decimal point.